# Why data cannot display using telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I want to try using telerik grid because I see the demo that the grid is really good, but I had a problem the data cannot display in my view. here is the view code

```
@{Html.Telerik().Grid<WarnaWarni.Models.TBL_BERITA>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .PrefixUrlParameters(false)
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.JUDUL).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.RINGKASAN).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ISI).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(o => o.FOTO);
        columns.Bound(o => o.TANGGAL).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(120);
    }).DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("ID_BERITA", "TBL_BERITA"))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable();

    }
```

here is the controller method:

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        string query = "select * from TBL_BERITA";            
        var a = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<TBL_BERITA>(query);

        return View(a.ToList());
    }
```

How to make the data show in the View?

Comment: There are a number of other moving parts that have to also work, like controller methods and proper routing.  Do you have those?

Comment: @Robert: I have update the code in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Ajax binding but you don't have a method that fill up your grid. Try passing in your model like this

```
@{Html.Telerik().Grid(WarnaWarni.Models.TBL_BERITA)
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{ ...
}
```

If you would like to have an ajax binding then you would need to add a method to your controller

Comment: What kind of method do I need to add in my controller? My controller just like I wrote in my question

Comment: see the Ajaxbinding method here under controller
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/ajaxbinding

Comment: I had looked the example, but they write GetOrder() what is the meaning?

Comment: I have solved the problem I am using Server Binding so I remove the ajax syntax. Thanks for your help